# How do I make a Google Calendar API event bi-weekly in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, google-calendar-api

```js
 this.state.gapi.auth2
        .getAuthInstance()
        .signIn()
        .then(() => {
          const event = {
            summary: this.state.event.summary,
            location: this.state.event.location,
            description: this.state.event.description,
            start: {
              dateTime: new Date(this.state.start.dateTime),
              timeZone: 'America/Chicago',
            },
            end: {
              dateTime: new Date(this.state.end.dateTime),
              timeZone: 'America/Chicago',
            },
            recurrence: ['RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=1'],
            reminders: {
              useDefault: false,
              overrides: [
                { method: 'email', minutes: 24 * 60 },
                { method: 'popup', minutes: 10 },
              ],
            },
          };
```

['RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=1'], I know this is what's setting that recurrence but I'm not certain how to phrase it for one day every other week.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that in your case, `BYDAY` might be able to be used. For example, when you want to set the events every Tuesday in the week, `RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=TU` can be used to the value of `recurrence`. `TU` is Tuesday. In this case, as the 1st day, the values of `dateTime` of the start and end are required to be for a day like `"2020-12-15T12:00:00"` and `"2020-12-15T13:00:00"` for `start` and `end`, respectively. Please be careful this.

As a sample, when you want to set the event from `"2020-12-15T12:00:00"` to `"2020-12-15T13:00:00"` every Tuesday in the week and the event is until `20201231`, please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
recurrence: ['RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=1'],
```

#### To:

```
recurrence: ['RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=TU;UNTIL=20201231'],  //  or UNTIL=20201231T000000Z
```

- In this case, as the 1st day, please set the values of `dateTime` of the start and end to `"2020-12-15T12:00:00"` and `"2020-12-15T13:00:00"`, respectively.
- And also, `UNTIL` is used.

#### References:

- [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)
- [RFC5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5)

  > `recurrence[]`: List of RRULE, EXRULE, RDATE and EXDATE lines for a recurring event, as specified in RFC5545. Note that DTSTART and DTEND lines are not allowed in this field; event start and end times are specified in the start and end fields. This field is omitted for single events or instances of recurring events.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!!! To set a bi-weekly recurrence on an event you need to set the freq to weekly and then have an interval of 2.

For example my event is every other thursday.

```html
['RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=TH;INTERVAL=2']
```